# Using Wordpress WP_Filesystem_Direct with PSR-4 autoloading

Tags: php, wordpress, autoload, psr-4

I am utilizing composer w/ PSR-4 autoloading in a Wordpress plugin.
No probs.

I went to use the `WP_Filesystem_Direct` class to remove a directory in a certain circumstance, but I found that I HAD to include 3 Wordpress classes manually using `require` in order to get things to work as expected.

Can anyone explain why I had to require them, and simply `using` them wouldn't work?

The following is the code that worked:

```
namespace Cre\API;

use \WP_Filesystem_Direct;

class ThingSync extends Sync
{
    public function checkPostProcessTasks()
    {
        // Why do I need this, and 'using' them above the class won't work?
        require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-base.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-includes/class-wp-error.php');

        if (get_option('deleteDir') !== "on") {
            $fs = new WP_Filesystem_Direct(false);
            $fs->rmdir(IMAGE_PATH, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The PSR-4 autoloader can not load this class because it does not conform to PSR-4 requirements. The class must be namespaced and the file name must match the class name. E.g., `WP_Filesystem_Direct` should be named something like `\Wp\Filesystem\Direct` and located in a file like `Wp\Filesystem\Direct.php`.

Comment: Gotcha!  Thank you :)  This will help me solves these problems way faster in the future.  If you make a full answer I'll mark it as correct!